# c# - Reading commandline args with their associated values

Tags: c#, command-line, console-application, args, command-line-arguments

Was just wondering whether there is a way to read in commandlines in a console app with values. I can read in commandlines easily enough but can't seem to find any info about obtaining values from a commandline.

For example(args):

```
aTest = 5; bTest = 13;
```

Would there be a way to read in the arg `aTest` an associate it with the int 5...?

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try something to parse those values? What results do you have now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a helper method for me along time ago, which extracts the value of a swtich or returns if present or not - this will help you maybe.

```
/// <summary>
/// If the arguments are in the format /member=value
/// Than this function returns the value by the given membername (!casesensitive) (pass membername without '/')
/// If the member is a switch without a value and the switch is preset the given ArgName will be returned, so if switch is presetargname means true..
/// </summary>
/// <param name="args">Console-Arg-Array</param>
/// <param name="ArgName">Case insensitive argname without /</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static string getArgValue(string[] args, string ArgName)
{
    var singleFound = args.Where(w => w.ToLower() == "/" + ArgName.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
    if (singleFound != null)
        return ArgName;


    var arg = args.Where(w => w.ToLower().StartsWith("/" + ArgName.ToLower() + "=")).FirstOrDefault();
    if (arg == null)
        return null;
    else
        return arg.Split('=')[1];
}
```

**Example:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    var modeSwitchValue = getArgValue(args, "mode");
    if (modeSwitchValue == null)
    {
        //Argument not present
        return;
    }
    else
    { 
        //do something
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ah nice- thanks!

arg.Split

I wasn't aware of this function!

Thanking you :):)

c# nub :/

Comment: @Anonagon if it fits your requirements - mark as answer plz ;)

Comment: Why not move the statements into the FirstOrDefault? args.FirstOrDefault(w => w.ToLower() == "/" + ArgName.ToLower()); should yield the same result, same with the second statement.

Answer (score 0):

This works find for your input as provided:

```
var args = "aTest = 5; bTest = 13;";

var values =
    args
        .Split(new [] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(x => x.Trim().Split('=').Select(y => y.Trim()).ToArray())
        .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => int.Parse(x[1]));
```

I get this result:

[image: result]